Displaying a large table over several pages with text wrapping of cells in a larger document
Edit: David Carlisle identified the issue with the table being contained to one page in a comment. I removed the commands to begin and end table (leaving them in my code below with a % before them for others to see what the mistake was). I am still having issues getting a right hand border on the table.
Edit 2: My table was not displaying the right hand border. This was due to an artefact from an earlier attempt to wrap text that I had forgot to remove. I was using a 'multicolumn' command that was overriding the wrapping on the text and causing the right hand border to disappear. Removing those commands and the begin and end table pointed out by David has left me with the table I want.
I am attempting to put a large table into an overleaf document. It runs for more than one page, has multiple columns, and needs to wrap text in the cells. So far, I have managed to set the column widths and wrap the text. However, the table abruptly ends after one page and there is no right hand table boundary. Please see the picture below if that isn't a clear description.
I have tried longtable with the following code (there is a bunch more rows in the ... but I excluded them for brevity:
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

%\begin{table}[h]
%\centering

\begin{longtable}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Exposure Category} & \textbf{Exposure} & \textbf{N} & \textbf{Source} & \textbf{Recoding Technique} & \textbf{Notes} \\ \hline 
Employment & Current employment status & 501631 & \cite{Modini2016TheMeta-review} & Binary: In paid employment or self-employed (1) and retired, student, unpaid, unemployed (0) & Most the beneficial effect of working seems to stem from the contrast to being unemployed \cite{TheMedicine} The magnitude of the health effects of Part-time work in the United States was moderated by the state \cite{Donnelly2021Part-timePolicies} - Highlighting the need to interact employment status with environmental and socio-economic conditions. \\ \hline 
...

\caption{My Long Table}
\label{long_table}
\end{longtable}

%\end{table}

I get a cautionary message about hbox being overfull and 'badness 10000' but am unsure what that means or how to fix it. I found a post suggesting deleting all vertical line spacing between rows (the \ \hline) but that completely broke the table.
Does anyone know how to make this table display over multiple pages with a border around the entirety of it? Thanks in advance and sorry if my question is not very clear. I'm new to latex


please always post a document that shows the problem but never do \begin{table}[h]\centering\begin{longtable} a table is an umbreakable box that always appears on one page, do not put a longtable inside table

just remove \begin{table}[h] \centering and\end{table} and add the missing \begin{document} and \documentclass

Thanks David. The table now is displaying over multiple pages. I have edited my code in the question to display your answer. Any ideas on how to get the right hand border of the table to display?

you are using fixed widths columns that are wider than you text width, so  you need a wider page or narrower columns the question is probably a duplicate of any of these https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btables%5D+too+wide

Thanks! I will try and fix the column width issue and will update my question if I manage to figure it out.

Please don't put solutions in to question posts, it messes up the site question and answer format, either close as a duplicate or post a separate answer post.

My main suggestion is that you switch from longtable to xltabular, which combines the capabilities of longtable (span multiple pages) and tabularx (set a target width -- usually, but not necessarily -- \linewidth). I would further recommend that you get rid of all vertical rules and replace the \hline directives with the macros of the booktabs package to generate a more open and inviting "look".

\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as appropriate
\usepackage{xltabular} % for 'xltabular' environment
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} % suppress full justification
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize}X}  % suppress full justification
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{Employment} % measure desired width of first and second column

\begin{document}

%\begin{table}[h]
%\centering

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}
    P{\mylen}
    P{\mylen}
    l % use natural column width
    l % use natural column width
    L{0.667} % note: 0.667 + 1.333 = 2.0 = # of X-type columns in table
    L{1.333}
    @{}}

%% headers and footers

\caption{My Long and Wide Table}
\label{long_table}\\
\toprule
Exposure Category & Exposure & $N$ & Source & Recoding Technique & Notes \\ 
\midrule 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\[1ex]
\toprule
Exposure Category & Exposure & $N$ & Source & Recoding Technique & Notes \\ 
\midrule 
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{6}{r@{}}{\footnotesize (continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot


%% body of table

Employment & Current employment status & 501631 & 
\cite{Modini2016TheMeta-review} & 
Binary: In paid employment or self-employed~(1); and retired, student, unpaid, unemployed~(0). & 
Most of the beneficial effect of working seems to stem from the contrast to being unemployed~\cite{TheMedicine}. The magnitude of the health effects of part-time work in the United States was moderated by the state~\cite{Donnelly2021Part-timePolicies}, highlighting the need to interact employment status with environmental and socio-economic conditions. \\ 


\end{xltabular}
\end{document}


With use of tabularray package table code is simple and concise:
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}  % set page parameters as appropriate

\usepackage{ragged2e}       % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage{tabularray}     % for 'longtblr' environment
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {My Long and Wide Table},
  label = {long_table}
                ]{%colsep=4pt,
                  colspec = {@{} X 
                                 X[0.8, j]
                                 Q[c, si={table-format=6}] l 
                                 X[1.2, j,cmd=\RaggedRight] 
                                 X[2,j,cmd=\RaggedRight] 
                             @{}},
                  row{1}  = {guard, b},
                 rowhead = 1
                  }
%% body of table
    \toprule
{Exposure\\ Category}
    & Exposure  
        & $N$  
            & Source 
                & {Recoding\\ Technique}  
                    & Notes         \\ 
    \midrule
Employment 
    & {Current\\ employment\\ status}
        & 501631 
            & \cite{Modini2016TheMeta-review} 
                & Binary: In paid employment or self-employed~(1); and retired, student, unpaid, unemployed~(0). 
                    &   Most of the beneficial effect of working seems to stem from the contrast to being unemployed~\cite{TheMedicine}. The magnitude of the health effects of part-time work in the United States was moderated by the state~\cite{Donnelly2021Part-timePolicies}, highlighting the need to interact employment status with environmental and socio-economic conditions. 
                    \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}


